# Unable to create Aws Emr Cluster using Java Sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, aws-java-sdk

I was starting an AWS ERM cluster using Java SDK (below is a code snippet) which worked perfectly fine.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKeyId);
AmazonElasticMapReduce emrClient = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                    .withRegion(region)
                    .build();

JobFlowInstancesConfig jobFlowInstanceConfig = new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                .withEc2SubnetId("subnetId")
                .withEc2KeyName("ec2KeyName") 
                .withInstanceCount(3) 
                .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)    
                .withMasterInstanceType(c5.4xlarge)
                .withSlaveInstanceType(c5.4xlarge); 


        // create the cluster
        RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
                .withName("clusterName")
                .withReleaseLabel("emr-5.23.0")
                .withApplications("<Added following in applications Hadoop,Spark,Ganglia,Zeppelin>")
                .withLogUri("s3 path")
                .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
                .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
                .withInstances(jobFlowInstanceConfig);

RunJobFlowResult runJobFlowResult = emrClient.runJobFlow(request);
```

Later on in another AWS Environment, a Role was created by our AWS Team to create cluster from a particular EC2 instance. But I am unable to create a cluster. 
Below is the code snippet with additional configuration, and changes that I notice with respect to my previous configuration.

1. No accessKeyId and secretAccessKeyId
2. EMR_EC2_DefaultRole changes to configured Role
3. Security Configuration was added

   ```
   AmazonElasticMapReduce emrClient = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.standard()
                   .withRegion(region)
                   .build();

   JobFlowInstancesConfig jobFlowInstanceConfig = new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
               .withEc2SubnetId("subnetId")
               .withEc2KeyName("ec2KeyName") 
               .withInstanceCount(3) 
               .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)    
               .withMasterInstanceType(c5.4xlarge)
               .withSlaveInstanceType(c5.4xlarge); 

   RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
               .withName("clusterName")
               .withReleaseLabel("emr-5.23.0")
               .withApplications("<Added following in applications Hadoop,Spark,Ganglia,Zeppelin>")
               .withLogUri("s3 path")
               .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
               .withJobFlowRole("name-of-role-created")
               .withInstances(jobFlowInstanceConfig)
               .withSecurityConfiguration("Security configuration Name");

   RunJobFlowResult runJobFlowResult = emrClient.runJobFlow(request);
   ```

I get following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.AmazonElasticMapReduceException: Role '' is not well-formed. (Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 0d5ed77e-ed0e-49fd-bd33-f88213ce08c3)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1356)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1102)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:759)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:733)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:675)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:657)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:521)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.doInvoke(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:2043)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.invoke(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:2010)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.invoke(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:1999)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.executeRunJobFlow(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:1770)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.runJobFlow(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:1742)
```

As the above error said that role is not properly formatted, I tried with different formats as well still got the same issue. Below are different formats which I added in .withJobFlowRole("name-of-role-created")

```
arn:aws:iam::639116131780:role/name-of-role-created
arn:aws:iam::639116131780:instance-profile/name-of-role-created
arn:aws:iam::639116131780:role/name-of-role-created/*
arn:aws:iam::639116131780:instance-profile/name-of-role-created/*
arn:aws:sts::639116131780:assumed-role/name-of-role-created
arn:aws:sts::639116131780:assumed-role/name-of-role-created/*
```

I get the same error everytime.

```
com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.AmazonElasticMapReduceException: Role 'arn:aws:iam::639116131780:role/name-of-role-created' is not well-formed. (Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 0d5ed77e-ed0e-49fd-bd33-f88213ce08c3)
```

Comment: Have you understood my answer? I could explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JobFlowRole` is the role that applied to the EMR instances and **it is not the role to use when you create the EMR**. I think You misread the option.

If you want to apply the role for not using API Keys, then you have to dig your AWS credentials. For example in S3,

```
S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
              .credentialsProvider(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().build())
              .build();
```

where

```
InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().build()
```

uses the role of the instance.

Comment: I solved this. Yes you were right that this was not the role to create EMR. But irrespective of providing InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().build() I was able create the cluster. I used default roles and did not use credentials. Asked our AWS team to change permissions of default role.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html#EMR-RunJobFlow-request-JobFlowRole), the `JobFlowRole` parameter is not an ARN, but just a string, like `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` (the default value). Use a format like that.